# Is "fighting" used as a gerund in this sentence?

Tags: gerunds, ing

Is "fighting" used as a gerund in this sentence?

> A soldier’s death is a grim reminder that more Americans have **died fighting** the Taliban and other insurgent groups in 2019 than in any other year since 2014, when the Pentagon euphemistically announced the “end of combat operations” in the country

Is "fighting" used as a gerund in the above sentence, or in the sense "when they were fighting (the Taliban)?

Comment: Not a gerund in the sense of a verb functioning as a noun. It's just a verb in the present continuous. It means "in the process of / engaged in" fighting.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Essentially a participial phrase functioning as an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

> A soldier’s death is a reminder that more Americans have died fighting 
>   the Taliban in 2019 than in any other year since 2014.

TLDR:

It’s difficult to answer your *yes–no* question directly because I’m not sure what you think being a “gerund” is supposed to mean in English, and because this is not a term that’s used much in modern English grammar.

So what I will instead do is explain these two things you need to know:

1. What that word’s *part of speech* is: it’s a ***verb*** because it has a direct object argument.
2. What its clause’s *grammatical role* is: it’s an ***adverbial*** because it’s modifying not complementing another verb.

---

Your original sentence is a complex declarative sentence containing not 
just one main clause but also two subordinate ones.  It also involves an
embedded *than*-comparison with an absent but recoverable verb of its very
own, but we won’t talk about that here.

Your sentence’s main clause necessarily uses a tensed finite verb, but only
one of your two subordinate clauses does so. The other subordinate clause
instead uses an untensed nonfinite verb, and it is this nonfinite
subordinate clause which you’ve asked about, the one containing an *‑ing* verb.

As far as parts of speech go, the word *fighting* in your sentence is
neither a noun nor an adjective; it is clearly a verb. You can know this with
absolute certainty because *fighting* has a direct object, and having
direct objects is a property peculiar to verbs alone (and to active
transitive verbs in particular).

*Fighting* is the verb of the nonfinite clause *fighting the Taliban and
other insurgent groups*. Like many nonfinite clauses, this one has no grammatical subject. It does,
however, have a grammatical object, because its direct object is *the
Taliban and other insurgent groups*.

However, your question suggests that you want to know more than one word’s
part of speech taken in isolation.  You appear to be interested in learning
the grammatical role which that entire phrase is fulfilling as a syntactic
constituent.

Nonfinite clauses are able to serve in any grammatical role normally
fulfilled by substantives (like nouns and pronouns) or by modifiers (like
adjectives or adverbs).  So now we need to figure out whether your entire
clause here is acting in ① a substantive role or ② in a modifier role.

The answer is that the second of those two possibilities applies. It’s
acting in a modifier role because one syntactic constituent is itself
modifying another syntactic constituent.

In particular, your *fighting* clause is acting as an adjunct to the other
subordinate clause, the one with the finite verb *have died*.  Because your
clause is an adjunct to another clause, syntactically yours is a modifier.
Only if yours had been been a core argument to that other clause’s verb
(like by being its subject or direct object) would it have been used
in a substantive role.  But it isn’t one of those. It’s only a modifier.

Modifiers of verbs are — by virtue of simple definition — always classified
as adverbial modifiers, never as adjectival modifiers.  (Only in rare cases
can adverbs modify nouns, but this is a verb that’s being modified here, so
there’s no question of that anyway.)

So your *fighting the Taliban* clause is itself an adverbial phrase
that’s modifying the verb phrase *have died*. It’s limiting that verb
by saying how the Americans who died did so.

Once upon a time this clause would have been called an adverbial
participial phrase under outdated grammars of English.  But modern English
grammars avoid words like *gerund* and *participle*, especially when trying
to describe a verb clause like yours. Often modern grammars prefer the
fused term *gerund-participle* for the verb’s *‑ing* inflection in
nonfinite verb clauses like yours here.

Comment: I must be out of the loop. I didn't realize 'gerund' had gone out of fashion.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking tchrist (the answer is excellent), but the main (copular) clause contains three  subordinate clauses : two finite and one non-finite. Each is at a different level in the sentence structure. The highest level subordinate clause is the complement of the nominal "grim reminder" (the NP "a grim reminder that.." is the predicative complement of course) . It contains a non-finite clause functioning as the verb phrase adjunct/modifier (fighting the Taliban..) and a relative clause supplement "when the Pentagon..", with "2014" as its anchor.

Answer (score -1):

> in the sense "when they were fighting (the Taliban)?

Yes. In basic terms, it is a participle that forms an adverbial participle phrase "when they were fighting (the Taliban), which modifies "died."